# JavaScript ArrayBuffer "detaches" when constructing a new Rust Vec via WASM

Tags: javascript, rust, webassembly

The basic idea is that a pointer is returned and then an image will be displayed using the pointer after creating a `Vec` at each video frame:

JavaScript:

```
var ptr = exports.alloc(size);
let bytes = new Uint8ClampedArray(exports.memory.buffer, ptr, size);
let image = new ImageData(bytes, 320, 240);

function tick() {
    requestAnimationFrame(tick);
    ctx.drawImage(video, 0, 0, width, height);
    let imageData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, width, height).data;
    bytes.set(imageData);
    exports.create_vector();
    ctx.putImageData(img, 0, 0);
}
```

Rust:

```rust
#[no_mangle]
pub extern "C" fn alloc(capacity: usize) -> *mut c_void {
    let mut buf = Vec::with_capacity(capacity);
    let ptr = buf.as_mut_ptr();
    mem::forget(buf);
    return ptr as *mut c_void;
}

#[no_mangle]
pub extern "C" fn create_vector() {
    let _: Vec<u8> = Vec::with_capacity(320 * 240);
}
```

[Here is the actual code](https://github.com/jonysy/wasmtest).

Here are the error messages:

**Chrome:**

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot perform %TypedArray%.prototype.set on a detached ArrayBuffer
    at Uint8ClampedArray.set (<anonymous>)
    at tick
```

**Safari:**

```
This webpage was reloaded because a problem occurred
```

**Mozilla:**

```
DOMException: "An attempt was made to use an object that is not, or is no longer, usable"

TypeError: Underlying ArrayBuffer has been detached from the view
```

The main culprits seem to be:

```
let bytes = new Uint8ClampedArray(exports.memory.buffer, ptr, size);
// ...
    exports.create_vector();
// ...
```

i.e., the browser crashes when I try to use `ptr` again after calling `exports.create_vector`.

What is going wrong here? Is there a solution?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When you allocate a new buffer and there is not enough memory allocated by the WASM "process" for it, the browser will allocate a new, larger buffer and will copy all data into it from the old location. It's quite transparent inside the WASM interpreter, but all pointers passed to JavaScript (with which you construct `Uint8ClampedArray`) get invalidated. There are two solutions to my knowledge:

- Allocate enough memory in the WASM "process" at initialization and immediately deallocate it so pointers will not get invalidated so long as memory usage is lower than the selected size.
- Keep track of buffers passed to JavaScript and "renew" pointers on such errors.